# Timer is the best way to achieve recursive in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm changing the Viewpager items Programmatically using `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` with a regular interval of time recursively. Below code works fine. please tell me, is it a best way to achieve this or is there any problem with my code. Thanks in advance.

```
    ViewPager mViewPager ;
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(backgroundimages.length), 1, 5000);

    private class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    int mLength = 0;

    public UpdateTimeTask(final int length) {
        this.mLength = length;
    }

    public void run() {
        mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1 < mLength) {
                    Updateviewpager(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                } else {
                    Updateviewpager(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void Updateviewpager(int position) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project you better ask it in CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, i didn't know that. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

i.e.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
```

}.start();

This way you are not running any extra thread.

Comment: But this will stop after 30000 milliseconds. I want it to be repeat it indefinitely ..

Comment: in onFinish() method call onStart(). It will run indefinitely :)